# I can see JSON object, but can't access values

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting a JSON object using the following code:

```
// Check that the token has been updated, then submit the form as required
$.when( $.getJSON(url + 'scripts/json.php'), button).then(function(json, button) {

}
```

If I output the values in the console window as follows:

```
console.log(json);
```

I get the following:

```
[Object { token="cdad8422e88787958729e21cce102cb0"}, "success", Object { readyState=4, responseText="{"token":"cdad8422e88787958729e21cce102cb0"}", status=200, more...}]
```

But trying to get the value of 'token' using this:

```
console.log(json.token);
```

I get 'undefined'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Array with Objects in it. You can access it via `json[0].token`.

Answer (score 0):

If you using jQuery's `$.ajax()`, don't forget to specify `jsonType:'json'` (`T` in `Type` is upper case, not `jsontype:'json'`.

Example: this script will get an undefined JSON result.

```
$.ajax({
  url:'server',
  datatype:'json',
  data:'your param',
  success:function(JSONResponse,status,xhr){

    //.....your code
  }   
})
```

If you use a lower case `t` in `type`, the JSON result will not be defined. So USE `dataType` with an upper case `T` which will be `dataType:'json'`.